# Replace only certain values in column based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe that contains many columns, but the relevant ones are: ID (this is number assigned to subject), Time (time at which this subject's measurement was taken) and Concentration.
A very simplified example would be:

```
df <- data.frame( ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
                  Concentration=c("XXX",0.3,0.7,0.6,"XXX","XXX",0.8,0.3,"XXX","XXX",
                                  "XXX",0.6,0.1,0.1,"XXX"),
                  Time=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5))
```

I would like to replace **only** the "XXX" values in column Concentration based on the following conditions:

1. when the value in column Time is less than or equal to 3; "XXX"==0
2. when the value in column Time is greater than 3; "XXX" should be replaced with the word "Missing"
   **unless** two consecutive "XXX" values appear for a single subject (ID) for Time>3 then the first
   consecutive "XXX" should be replaced with 0.05 and the second consecutive "XXX" (or all the following "XXX" values if there are more) should be replaced with the word "Missing".

I have tried mutate_at and replace_na, some ifelse statements and case_when but I just cannot seem to figure out how to correctly do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Just to show some work:

```
df[df == "XXX" & df$Time<3] <- as.numeric(0)
df[df == "BLQ" & df$Time>3] <- as.character("Missing")
```

I have managed to find a simple and robst solution that takes care of the first two parts of my problem what I'm stuck on is the last part - when there are two or more consecutive "XXX" values for a single subject after Time>3. I imagine I should loop an ifelse statement over and index list of the ID's or something like that, but I can't figure out how to do that.
It's very important that the ID's are somehow seperated here because there could be "XXX" as the final Concentration of one ID and as the first Concentration of the next ID and I do not want that to be read as two consecutive "XXX" values for a single ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using some functions of tidyverse, and I also added some other records to your example.

```
rm(list = ls(all=TRUE))

require(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame( ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                  Concentration=c("XXX",0.3,0.7,0.6,"XXX","XXX",0.8,0.3,"XXX","XXX",
                                  "XXX",0.6,0.1,0.1,"XXX",0.2,"XXX","XXX",1),
                  Time=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

df <- tibble(df) %>% 
  mutate(Concentration = as.character(Concentration),
         Concentration_Original = Concentration) %>% 
  mutate(Concentration = ifelse(Concentration == 'XXX' & Time <= 3, "0", Concentration)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Concentration = ifelse(Concentration == 'XXX' & Concentration == lead(Concentration),
                                  "0.05", ifelse(Concentration == 'XXX',
                                                 "Missing", Concentration))) %>% 
  replace_na(list(Concentration = "Missing")) %>% ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

I *just* had to figure this out a few minutes ago and found this question while looking for a better version. Here's mine:

```
value_swap <- function(dataset, specified_columns, original_val, new_val){ 
temp. <- dataset 
   temp.[, specified_columns][
    temp.[, specified_columns] == original_val] <- new_val
return(temp.)
}
value_swap(mtcars, c("cyl","gear"), 4, 3.99)
```

You'll notice the 4s in the cylinder and gear columns mtcars are now 3.99, but the carb column is left alone.

As for your conditionals; you can just subset your dataset into 3 different ones based on your conditions, run the custom value_swaps for each condition, then rbind them back. Much simpler than doing a giant nested one in my opinion.