# Insert condition (column A value) into function based on a value in a different column (B)

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

This is a follow-up to a question I previously asked ([Replace only certain values in column based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65106274/replace-only-certain-values-in-column-based-on-multiple-conditions)). For context I'm including some of the same information.

I have a large dataframe that contains many columns, but the relevant ones are: ID (this is number assigned to subject), Time (time at which this subject's measurement was taken) and Concentration. A very simplified example would be:

```
df <- data.frame( ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
                  Concentration=c("XXX",0.3,0.7,0.6,"XXX","XXX",0.8,0.3,"XXX","XXX",
                                  "XXX",0.6,0.1,0.1,"XXX"),
                  Time=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5))
```

I would like to replace only the "XXX" values in column Concentration based on the following conditions:

1. when the value in column Time is less than or equal to *timeX* ; "XXX"==0
2. when the value in column Time is greater than *timeX*; "XXX" should be replaced with the word "Missing" unless two consecutive "XXX" values appear for a single subject (ID) for Time>*timeX* then the first consecutive "XXX" should be replaced with 0.05 and the second consecutive "XXX" (or all the following "XXX" values if there are more) should be replaced with the word "Missing".

It's very important that the ID's are somehow seperated here because there could be "XXX" as the final Concentration of one ID and as the first Concentration of the next ID and I do not want that to be read as two consecutive "XXX" values for a single ID.

The solution I have, for when we assume *timeX*=3 is:

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(df) %>% 
  mutate(Concentration = as.character(Concentration),
         Concentration_Original = Concentration) %>% 
  mutate(Concentration = ifelse(Concentration == 'XXX' & Time <= 3, "0", Concentration)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Concentration = ifelse(Concentration == 'XXX' & Concentration == lead(Concentration),
                                  "0.05", ifelse(Concentration == 'XXX',
                                                 "Missing", Concentration))) %>% 
  replace_na(list(Concentration = "Missing")) %>% ungroup()
```

To make the code more flexible and more importantly so that it doesn't require the user to manually check what the time cut off point should be and then manually insert it, I've been trying to make the code more automatic.

I would like to replace Time <= 3 with the following condition for *timeX*:
*timeX* is the value in column Time *for that specific subject ID* at which the value in column concentration is the highest. So basically the condition should be that *timeX* is that at which the concentration achieves it's maximum value.
For example: For ID 1 in my df, the highest concentration would be 0.7 and that concentration is achieved at Time = 3 so the value 3 should be inserted as *timeX* value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts/suggestions that might be helpful.

First, if you wish to look at maximum value for `Concentration`, I would not have this column be of character type. Instead, would make it numeric, and use `NA` for missing values. The first `mutate` sets that up.

After grouping, you can use `mutate` and `case_when` for your various situations. You can access the `Time` of maximum concentration through:

```
Time[which(Concentration == max(Concentration, na.rm = TRUE))]
```

(removing the missing values).

If it the `Concentration` is missing, and `Time` is less than the `Time` of maximum concentration, then change to 0.

In second case, if `lead` (or subsequent row) also is missing, then change to .05.

Otherwise, do not change `Concentration`.

Depending on further analyses and presentation, you can use "Missing" as a text label for missing data.

**Edit**: Based on OP comment, it appears that only the *first* "XXX" after max time should be replace with .05 for concentration, but all the following "XXX" after that as missing. To achieve this, add:

```
!is.na(lag(Concentration, default = 0))
```

as a condition for determining if value should be .05. The logic is: if the previous row's value is *not* `NA`, but the following value *is* `NA`, after the max time, then change to .05.

Here is the modified code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Concentration = ifelse(Concentration == "XXX", NA_character_, Concentration),
         Concentration = as.numeric(Concentration)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Concentration_New = case_when(
    is.na(Concentration) & Time < first(Time[which(Concentration == max(Concentration, na.rm = TRUE))]) ~ 0,
    is.na(Concentration) & Time > last(Time[which(Concentration == max(Concentration, na.rm = TRUE))]) & 
      is.na(lead(Concentration, default = 0)) & !is.na(lag(Concentration, default = 0)) ~ .05,
    TRUE ~ Concentration
  ))
```

**Output**

```
      ID Concentration  Time Concentration_New
   <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>             <dbl>
 1     1          NA       1              0   
 2     1           0.3     2              0.3 
 3     1           0.7     3              0.7 
 4     1           0.6     4              0.6 
 5     1          NA       5             NA   
 6     2          NA       1              0   
 7     2           0.8     2              0.8 
 8     2           0.3     3              0.3 
 9     2          NA       4              0.05
10     2          NA       5             NA   
11     3          NA       1              0   
12     3           0.6     2              0.6 
13     3           0.1     3              0.1 
14     3           0.1     4              0.1 
15     3          NA       5             NA
```